# Applying a jQuery DataTable plug-in to dynamically generated tables from ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

My requirement is the following:

From my ASPX page I import data from a spreadsheet using fileUpload and dynamically generate an ASP.NET table. The table rows and columns dimensions and data are set by the file itself - that means my application has no knowledge of rows and columns until the data is imported.

What I would like to do is to apply jQuery DataTables plugin to my dynamically generated table. The table is generated when user clicks the Import button on the page.

The problem I have is that the jscript to format the table runs before the table is available and therefore DataTable plug-in complains about columns. The error reads:

> Unable to get value of the property 'aoColumns': object is null or undefined

I've tried to add the following code to my Button_Click event but it happens before the table is loaded:

> ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "FormatTable", "FormatTable();", True)

The jscript is the following:

> ```
>   function FormatTable() {
>                     var oTable = $('#tblMyTable).dataTable({
>                         "bJQueryUI": true,
>                         "sScrollY": "300px",
>                         "sScrollX": "100%",
>                         "sScrollXInner": "150%",
>                         "bScrollCollapse": true,
>                         "bPaginate": false
>                     });
>                     new FixedColumns(oTable);
>     };
> ```

I made sure the table is well-formed with table, thead, tr, th, tbody, tr, td. When the table is generated from code behind, it is inserted in a server placeholder control.

So my question is: how can I successfully format a server generated table using jQuery DataTables plug-in ? Thank you very for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want your code to execute after the DOM is ready. 
For this jQuery provides the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Call your `FormatTable` only after the DOM is ready as follows.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "FormatTable", 
                    @"$(document).ready(function() {FormatTable();});", True);
```

Comment: Hi nunespascal. Your suggestion worked brilliantly. Much appreciated. I'm up and running.